# TSNode + Mocha: Ignore TypeScript errors (make compiler emit on errors and make TSNode execute emitted code)

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, ts-node

In the below code, although function `test2` in invalid, it should not affect to testing of function `test1`:

```
export function test1(): boolean {
  return true;
}

export function test2(): number {
  return "1";
}
```

Test:

```
import { assert as Assert } from "chai";
import { test1 } from "./example";


describe("Example", (): void => {
  it("Example", (): void => {
    Assert.isTrue(test1());
  });
});
```

However Mocha, executed by TSNode will fail:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
Source/ProjectBuilder/example.ts(6,3): error TS2322: Type '"1"' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Possible to force TSNode to complete above test? TypeScript has option `noEmitOnError`...

My mocharc.yaml:

```yaml
extension:
  - ts
spec: "**/*.test.ts"
require:
  - ts-node/register
  - tsconfig-paths/register
```

### Why I need it

According the **Clean Architecture**, "Business rules must not depends on anything, and it must be testable". But even if business rules does not depend on views, controllers, etc., we can not test it if some errors in views, controllers, etc. exists.

When I modify business logic in my application, all that depend on it becomes invalid. Assume that in my entity in business logic `type User { name: string; age: number }` has been changed to type User `{ fullName: string; age: string; }`. All that depend on business logic (view, controllers, presenters, etc.) becomes invalid - I need to correct it too according updated to business logic.

```
// In business rules:

type User = { 
  ID: number;
  fullName: string; 
  age: string; // in past - number
}

// In controller:

class UserProfileController {
  // ...
  // All what comes from input field is string    ↓
  private onClickChangeUserAge(inputtedUserAge: string) {
    // This expression obeys to previous version of business rules!
    this.targetUser.age = Number(inputtedUserAge);
    // TypeScript will emit type error, when I try to test business rules,
    // however business rules does not depend on controller.
  }
}
```

However, in big application, this corrections could takes days, weeks and months. How we can get the feedback proves that at least business logic works properly and we are in right way?

Comment: You are confusing *compile time* with *run time*. The code, like a program in any statically-typed language, will not run if it does not compile: *it is not a valid Typescript program*. In the same way "@#$^%*^%arstlh" is not a valid Typescript program.

Comment: @JaredSmith, thank you for the comment. I know that Webpack can compile TypeScirpt (wisth ts-loader, off course) even there are errors in TypeScript. If it will be an error like calling property of `undefined`, JavaScript will be executed until this command. Is same thing possible with TSNode?

Comment: Why are you manually testing things the compiler checks for you? Why are you even bothering with Typescript if you're just going to try to subvert it? What's the point of all this? What are you *actually* trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @JaredSmith, Well, I'll explain. When I modify business logic in my application, all that depend on it becomes invalid. Ideally, I need to resolve all errors in my application before run tests, but it could take too long time. Instead of it, first I need to test modified business logic only. But because of above problem, I can not run Mocha.

Comment: I still don't get it. Again, *the compiler will do the type checking*. You *literally* (as you've discovered) *cannot* pass the wrong type to a function or return the wrong type from it, the code *won't even compile*, much less *run*. So you literally *can't* make a mistake like this, ergo such tests are pointless and you don't need them. This is the entire point of using a static type system. So either write your code in Javascript with appropriate tests for Javascript, or write it in Typescript with appropriate tests for Typescript. If you change the logic, again, your app won't compile.

Comment: @JaredSmith "So you literally can't make a mistake like this" Assume that in my business logic entity `type User { name: string; age: number }` changed to `type User { fullName: string; age: string; }`. All that depend on business logic (view, controllers, presenters, etc.) becomes invalid - I need to correct it too. However, in big application, this corrections could takes days, weeks and months, but I need the feedback proves that at least business logic works properly. No way to test just business logic ignoring became invalid view, controllers, etc?

Answer (score 0):

It would not make sense for you to ask Typescript to disregard types. What you are describing is akin to asking for a calculator that confirms that 2 + 2 = 5, only temporarily, because eventually you will ask for 2 + 3 = 5 but that might take a very long time.

The assumption in your question is that `number` and `string` are sufficiently compatible that your business logic will be sound regardless of whether `test2` returns `1` or `"1"`. This is not true: By way of example, `1 + 1 == 2`, `"1" + 1 == "11"`, and `"1" - 1 == 0`. Depending on which of those applies to your case, disregarding types may allow you to test your business logic, or may give you false confidence in a broken system. I would venture that in general the data types count as part of the business logic you're trying to verify--what would the data model count as, if not business logic?

Instead, what you are describing is a *gradual migration* during which the business rules ensure that `test2` returns `string | number`. By describing the migration accurately in the type system, you may be able to confirm that the business logic applies correctly--*if that is true across your migration*--and also provide a type that you can apply only from certain modules and call sites that can be tightened up as you finish the migration.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. "It would not make sense for you to ask Typescript to disregard types." - All that I ask from TSNode is build JavaScript and execute event if type error exists. Why what I asking from TSNode is possible for Webpack with TSLoader? Webpack will build script with `noEmitOnErrors: false` even if TypeErrors exists. Also, sorry that example with `test1` and `test2` is too far from real application: I assume that `test1` is part of business logic and `test2` is part of, for example, controller. I will add new example.

Comment: I consider yous answer as "It's impossible for now".

Comment: @GurebuBokofu If that is what I had meant, I would have written that. What I wrote is that "it would not make sense for you", and I stand by that as a summary.

Answer (score -2):

```
type User = { 
  ID: number;
  fullName: string; 
  age: string | number
}
```

You can specify both types to make migration easier and not use `//@ts-ignore` everywhere.

This will add proper suggestions everywhere like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but this solution is not salable. If we change just `User` entity, it will not take so mush time to correct other components, but if business logic will be rewritten on a large scale, if will be much easier to delete all except business logic an recreate if.